# Why is "bombshell" used to describe attractive women?

Tags: etymology, slang

[***Bombshell***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombshell_%28sex_symbol%29) is a term used to describe very attractive women, similar to the term "sex symbol". The phrase was notably used as [the title of a 1930's film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombshell_%28film%29), which incidentally led to [its lead actress being nicknamed a "blond bombshell"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Harlow), although the term may have been in use long before that.

Where did this term come from, and why? What's the relation between bombshells and attractive women?

Comment: I have specifically watched 100s of WWI documentaries and have heard the GIs use it in said docs.  I don't have sources so I won't leave it as an answer.  Also all of the answers below are really long comments and not answers.  Really should have guidelines on answering historical language questions...

Comment: @RyeBread if you can bring evidence that "bombshell" was used to describe women as far back as WWI I'll put a bounty on the question. Just leave me a comment so I can activate it. I won't promise that you'll get the bounty, but I do think your answer will generate some interest. (With permission from congusbongus of course.)

Comment: In documentaries about WWI, I see soldiers drew/pasted pictures of girlfriends/attractive women on the shell of their planes and bombs. Could this link bombshell to attractive women?

Comment: It certainly seems plausible that it arose from WWI GI jargon (or perhaps GI jargon from the interwar period).  As to painting pictures of girls on aircraft, I don't believe that became common until WWII or shortly before.

Comment: @HotLicks a phrase the OP has found in 1933 arose due to a war that started in 1939?

Comment: @JonHanna - I didn't say that the phrase arose during WWII, but I suspect the practice of painting women on aircraft did.  Hence no connection between the two.

Answer (score 9):

The OED's first quotation for a *bombshell* describing a woman is 1942, but it was indeed the [title of a 1933 film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023825/) starring Jean Harlow. In fact, the film was later renamed to *The Blonde Bombshell* so it's possible Harlow got the nickname from the movie.

(It appears in [a number of 1933 snippets in Google Books](https://encrypted.google.com/search?num=100&safe=off&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1933,cd_max:1933&tbm=bks&q=%22blonde%20bombshell%22&oq=%22blonde%20bombshell%22&gs_l=serp.3...1897.6458.0.6697.26.22.4.0.0.0.131.1447.19j3.22.0....0...1c.1.29.serp..15.11.608.krxlxEGFGKo) which could be misdated, but look correct.)

The earliest verifiable example I found is in the *[Spokane Daily Chronicle](http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=ZWpWAAAAIBAJ&sjid=9fQDAAAAIBAJ&pg=7159,5259478&dq=blonde-bombshell&hl=en)* - Nov 24, 1933:

> But it seems that Mr. [Lee] Tracy stepped out on a balcony in his pajamas and made wild gestures during a Mexico City parade, and now Mr. Tracy, a star with a long list of hits from "Blessed Event" to **"The Blonde Bombshell"** behind him, is no longer with at least not until things are "straightened out," if they ever are.

And from the UK:

R, H., 1933, Dec 09. THREE NEW FILMS. *The Manchester Guardian* (1901-1959), 16:

> Two of them, "The Cradle Song" and "L'Ordonnance," are by famous authors, the first Sierra and the second Maupassant, and have European stars, but the only completely successful one is the one with the least pretension, **"Blonde Bombshell,"** at the Empire.

The next day's *Observer* explains the name.

LEJUNE, C.A., 1933, Dec 10. The Pictures. The Observer (1901- 2003), 12. ISSN 00297712:

> And it is worth mentioning, in passing, that Hollywood cannot be blamed for the title. It is we, the audience, who have spoilt an arresting and altogether unusual title with that ridiculous adjective. When the film first came out in Hollywood, it was called **"Bombshell,"** *tout court*. But the public stayed away because they thought it was a war picture. **"Blonde Bombshell"** was the final compromise between dynamics and security. ...
>
> The story is nothing but a snatched handful of experiences form the life of Lola Burns, star of stars in the Monarch studios. She is their "It Girl," or, alternatively, their **Blonde Bombshell**--eruptive, starry-eyed, warm-hearted, a little fatuous.

---

Edit: [Bill Mullins found](http://listserv.linguistlist.org/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1310D&L=ads-l&P=R3485) slightly earlier references:

> The San Diego *Evening Tribune* 1 Nov 1933 p 8A col 5 has an ad for the
>   film (titled "Bombshell") with the line "A Blonde Bombshell in the
>   Picture That Has Thrown Hollywood Into Consternation!"
>
> The *LA Times* of that day has a small ad (sec II p 8 col 5) that reads:
>   "Last Times Today Jean Harlow Lee Tracy "The Blonde Bombshell" as if
>   that were the film's title.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough research but this doesn't answer the question.  The film used the word bombshell because it was already part of common slang.  The word came from WWI GI slang.  You can't say a word came from something because it was the first use you could find when googling.  If they used it for a movie title to describe a girl (especially in 1933) then obviously it had use well before.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the added benifit is of digging up three print references to a movie we have already ascertained existed.

Comment: @T.E.D. It's evidence that the film was renamed to "The Blonde Bombshell" in 1933, which also antedates the Oxford English Dictionary's 1942. Harlow was nicknamed the blonde bombshell (sometimes today called 'the original blonde bombshell'. Perhaps she got the nickname from the film. Perhaps only after that it became a known phrase. Or perhaps it was already was in use before that. Perhaps the film just popularised it. Perhaps not. But at least it's putting some stakes in the ground about the origin with print evidence.

Comment: @RyeBread: Was it WWI GI slang? I'd be very interested to see evidence of it. I didn't (only) search Google (Books and News), I used other newspaper databases too. Sometimes things used for movie titles are already in use, but sometimes it's the other way around too (recent example: bucket list), or that a movie popularises or mainstreams something.

Comment: @RyeBread: It's definitely possible *bombshell* was used during WWI to refer to a woman this way (although it was definitely used figuratively), but without documentary evidence we can't be sure. Is there even anecdotal evidence of its use then from someone who was alive then? / Do you know when was *bucket list* first used? I've not been able to find anything relevant before the film. / Also, if you have evidence of "G.I." referring to an enlisted US soldier before WWII, please share too :)

Comment: The LEJUNE article suggests that this film popularized the term, because at release time “the public stayed away because they thought [_Bombshell_ referred to] a war picture.” Unless you actually have some support for the claim that the slang meaning significantly predates the film, instead of just insinuating that it _probably_ did, you're impugning a good answer for no good reason. I find these kind of “this is not an answer, it's a verbose comment” criticisms non-constructive and hostile.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd - I think you might be thinking of WWII?  Given that aerial bombing (and aerial warfare in general) was a [relatively new invention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_bombing_during_World_War_I) in WWI, I would find it curious if the association between women and bombshells originated in that era.  Female-centric plane [nose art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nose_art) was also a WWII thing.  So it is possible that the movie in question was contemporary to those first uses.

Answer (score 3):

J.E. Lighter, *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1994) confirms the view expressed by congusbongus (in the original post above) and by Hugo, Talia Ford, and Mari-Lou A (in their answers) that the popular association of *bombshell* with "exceedingly attractive woman" begins with Jean Harlow's turn as Lola Burns in [*Bombshell*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023825/):

> **bombshell** *n.* a strikingly sexy woman. [First cited occurrence:] **1933** Mahin & Furthman *Bombshell* (film): I see Lola Burns, the bombshell herself.

A copyright entry for the play that the movie is based on—*Bombshell*, by Caroline Francke—appears in the Library of Congress's [Catalog of Copyright Entries](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yc5DAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA291&dq=%22bombshell+a+play+in+3+acts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMIotnfoMDPyAIVVuZjCh0whAaB#v=onepage&q=%22bombshell%20a%20play%20in%203%20acts%22&f=false) (1932), with a copyright date of October 22, 1932. According to [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0290462/), the play wasn't produced prior to the release of the Jean Harlow film.

A search of U.S. newspapers in the Chronicling America database (which covers the period from 1835 through 1922) turns up several instance where a female character or a female performer or a group of female performers are identified as "bombshell." From an [advertisement for performances at the National Hall](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82014594/1851-05-15/ed-1/seq-7/#date1=1836&sort=relevance&rows=20&words=Bombshell+LOVE&searchType=basic&sequence=0&index=4&state=&date2=1922&proxtext=lovely+bombshell&y=9&x=14&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2), in the *[Washington, D.C.] American Telegraph* (May 15, 1851):

> To conclude with the vaudeville of LOVE IN MASQUERADE. Aurelia, alias **Bombshell** ------ Mrs. M. Jones. Lucy --------------- Mrs. Cappell. Reserved seats 50 cents; Box seats 37 cts.; Gallery 25 cts.

From "[Among Us Mortals, Drawn by W.E. Hill: The Burlesque Show](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030214/1917-04-01/ed-1/seq-49/#date1=1900&index=0&rows=20&words=Bombshell&searchType=basic&sequence=0&state=&date2=1922&proxtext=bombshell&y=11&x=9&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)" (a series of satirical drawings of people with fictional identities) in the *New-York Tribune* (April 1, 1917):

> [Caption:] Lilly Romaine, soubrette on the programme as "The Little **Bombshell** of Joy," living up to her reputation.

From an [advertisement for a performance by Flo-Flo and Her Perfect "36" Chorus](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84027621/1920-02-02/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1900&index=3&rows=20&words=Beautiful+Bombshell&searchType=basic&sequence=0&state=&date2=1922&proxtext=beautiful+bombshell&y=13&x=16&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), in the *Ocala [Florida] Evening Call* (February 2, 1920):

> GORGEOUS GIRLS IN FEMININE FINERY[.] ITS EXHILARATING[,] INVIGORATING[,] INTOXICATING[,] REJUVENATING[.] A **Bombshell** of Youthful Beautiful Shapely Girlie Girls[.] Replete With Catchy Songs, Tuneful Music, Wit, Humor and Repartee[.] FULL OF PEP–LET'S GO[.] PRICES 77c, $1, $.150 and $2.00 Plus War Tax[.]

There is, in addition, this [advertisement for a film at the Please-U Theatre](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn90005351/1921-07-18/ed-1/seq-6/#date1=1836&index=0&rows=20&words=bombshell+love&searchType=basic&sequence=0&state=&date2=1922&proxtext=lovely+bombshell&y=12&x=19&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) described as a "melodramatic bombshell," from the *[St. Johnsbury, Vermont] Caledonian-Record* (July 18, 1921):

> Maurice Tourneur Offers "THE BAIT" With Exquisite Hope Hampton[.] A Paramount Picture adapted from the stage play "The Tiger Lay." A melodramatic **bombshell** of love, romance, and mystery. The Lights of Paris! The Shadows of New York all blended in one long thrill. Great supporting cast, all the superb scenic artistry that Tourneur is famous for!

A Google Books search of the period 1900–1932 finds multiple instances in which *bombshell* is used figuratively to mean "shocking or situation-changing revelation or event," but only one in which an author equates a bombshell with a female human being—and in that one the implication is not of high-voltage sexuality but of tranquility-destroying unpredictability and rashness. From Christopher Morley, [*The Haunted Bookshop*](https://books.google.com/books?id=E5bYq61WVZ8C&pg=PT28&dq=%22bombshell%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAjgyahUKEwjjyP6Zws_IAhWLN4gKHWOiB6o#v=onepage&q=%22bombshell%22&f=false) (1919):

> "Well?" said Roger, as Mrs. Mifflin made no comment. "Don't you think it will be rather interesting to get a naive young girl's reactions toward the problems of our tranquil existence?"
>
> "Roger, you blessed innocent!" cried his wife. "Life will no longer be tranquil with a girl of nineteen round the place. You may fool yourself, but you can't fool me. A girl of nineteen doesn't REACT toward things. She explodes. Things don't 'react' anywhere but in Boston and in chemical laboratories. I suppose you know you're taking a human **bombshell** into the arsenal?"
>
> Roger looked dubious. "I remember something in Weir of Hermiston about a girl being 'an explosive engine,'" he said. "But I don't see that she can do any very great harm round here. We're both pretty well proof against shell shock. The worst that could happen would be if she got hold of my private copy of Fireside Conversation in the Age of Queen Elizabeth. Remind me to lock it up somewhere, will you?"

Given the paucity of woman-as-bombshell references in the decades before the film *Bombshell* appeared in 1933, it seems unlikely that any of the earlier instances noted above had a significant influence on popular usage before the Harlow film appeared. But if nothing else, they show that equating a woman with an explosive device did not originate with Caroline Francke in 1932.

Answer (score 1):

When Jean Harlow, a [platinum blonde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platinum_Blonde_%28film%29), starred in *Bombshell* in 1933, the term *bomb-shell* had already been in use for at least 73 years ([etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bombshell)) in the sense of a "shattering or devastating thing or event." In most of her films, Harlow "was sluttish and smart, cracking gum and one-liners simultaneously: chewing up the scenery as the vulgar star of *Bombshell*" ([Molly Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molly_Haskell)). It stands to reason to conclude that the *blonde bombshell*, first attested in 1942, was derived directly from Jean Harlow's persona. That, however, is not a felicitous answer to the question of why the filmmakers of *Bombshell* chose exactly *that* metaphor over another similar one. Wasn't, say, *a volcano*, likewise both an event and a thing, just as fitting a metaphor? Its erruption (~ explosion) is shattering. And devastating. Could the *bombshell* have been, simply, an arbitrary choice? Not likely.

It had been only 15 years since the end of the Great War, and the notion of sudden devastation by bombing was still omnipresent, what with all the unexploded bombshells strewn around England, not to mention the Western Front ("iron harvest"). *Devastating* and *love* (a common euphemism for *passion*) often go together and always have. And then, there was also *the shape* of the thing—the thing—which might've been an additional reason why not the more frequent word *bomb* was chosen, but rather the *bombshell*, the former having some, whether more or less, abstract realizations, and the latter certainly being more denotative of a thing, of an object, i.e., of the woman-object. The *bomb* was waved aside despite its not yet having become burdened by the secondary meanings of success, a failure, a marijuana cigarette, a large sum of money (all those meanings sprung up after 1933, according to OED); and despite its being synonymous with *bombshell*. Interesting. The shape, then. Well, a picture being worth a thousand words:

[image]

[image]

OK, two words: mammary, phallic.

Here it might be opportune to quote Wikipedia, "The term bombshell is a forerunner to the term "sex symbol" and originally used to describe popular female sex icons. Modern slang refers to a bombshell as an extremely sexually attractive woman."

At the peril of sounding like a feminist, I'll posit that this sort of labeling is a typical male thing. Wasn't the "bullet bra" ("torpedo bra") invented by a man? (Yes it was, by Howard Hughes, no less, in 1941.) That military terminology crept into the civilian life was, understandably, partly due to the vicissitudes of the times, but I think it has just as much to do with the old story of sex and violence. So there you have it.

Comment: Harlow's film *Bombshell* was renamed *The Blonde Bombshell* in the same year, so can also be found in 1933. See my [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/132830/9001).

Comment: Thanks, Hugo. I saw your answer, but only after submitting mine. An important piece of information in your A is that the movie hadn't been named _Bombshell_ in a literal sense, and was later billed as _The Blond Bombshell_ only to ensure it was read figuratively. It remains a puzzle whether the people at MGM created the label or merely borrowed it.

Comment: Yes, it definitely already existed as a figurative use, but whether it was already in use to describe a woman is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

OED has

> **bombshell** A shattering or devastating act, event, etc. *Phr. **blonde bomb-shell,*** a fair-haired person, esp. a woman, of startling vitality or physique.

Using the word *bombshell* describes the (metaphorical) effect the person has on the observer.

[image]

[Glitters20.com](http://www.glitters20.com/quotes)

OED's earliest citation for *Blonde bombshell* is

> 1942   L. V. Berrey & M. Van den Bark *Amer. Thes. Slang* §184/14   Blonde Bombshell (as a nickname).

... so if you have documentary evidence of an earlier use they would probably like to know.

Comment: You should submit earlier evidence to the [OED here](http://oup.com/uk/oedsubform/).

Comment: I have trouble giving this answer much credit, as the question itself contains an earlier reference (one that isn't particularly hard to find, either).

Comment: @T.E.D. "What's the relation between bombshells and attractive women?"

Answer (score 0):

If  a woman is so incredibly stunning, you'd say she *blows your mind* [<sup>1</sup>](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+mind). The rush of adrenaline a man feels when looking at a woman they have a strong sexual attraction to can be almost violent in nature. Some people even speak of their hearts *exploding* with joy.

A bomb is a powerful weapon and its effects can be devastating, likewise the effects of a sexually attractive woman on men can be as traumatic or destructive.

**EDIT** and further reflections.

As I read the wikipedia link posted by Congusbongus, I saw that the original title for the film was indeed **Bombshell** [<sup>2</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bombshell1933movie.JPG) and I began to read the plot of the story. The story has nothing related to war or any type of aggressive conflict. So why the title? What did it mean? And why was it changed to the *Blonde Bombshell* so soon after its release?

Well the story is a comedy about a famous film star, Lola (Jean Harlow), and how she abandons Hollywood to pursue a more normal life. She falls in love with a wealthy man who has no idea of her past but in due course he makes a proposal of marriage. She accepts; however, her real identity is then revealed  by her studio publicist to the fiancé. On hearing the news, the affluent (and supercilious) lover is shocked, rejects Lola and calls off the marriage. Lola thereby returns to her former world, Hollywood.

It's clear from this context that the meaning of the title, bombshell, only made any sense at the end of the story i.e. **the bombshell is that Lola Burns is a famous movie star**. Likewise Gifford Middleton, her fiancé, drops (or dumps) her like a bomb, so the original title is actually a clever play on words.

Jean Harlow despite her very young age, was already a huge star in Hollywood, she had starred in several "block buster movies", among them [Platinum Blonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platinum_Blonde_%28film%29) released two years earlier in 1931. The public by now had identified Harlow as the sexy platinum *blonde* star and simply tagged the *blonde* epithet to the original film title, MGM renamed the movie, and the rest is history.

[image: movie poster of Blonde Bombshell]

Comment: According to [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=blow) "blows your mind" is recorded as being used in 1967; I suspect "bombshell" pre-dates it.

Comment: Was in use BY 1967. The point I was making, and which you also asked for, was the connection between bombshells and women used in the positive sense of course. Something which I forgot to add and no doubt someone will pick up on :)

Comment: This may be useful as a mnemonic, but I don't see any evidence that this is the source of the word itself.

Comment: @T.E.D. I never suggested that this was the source of "bombshell" I, hopefully, explained and illustrated that sex appeal can be expressed via more aggressive and hence, more virile terms.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that it derived from the fact that there was a chemical in bombs that caused hair to turn a very deep blonde colour. The chemical was discovered and then lots of women began to produce bombs in the factories with direct access to this carciologenic chemical.

Don't know if this is correct but it is what I have heard !!

Answer (score 0):

I watched Horrible Histories today and said that women used to steal gunpowder from the munitions factories as it bleached their hair but that it often had consequences being highly flammable, hence "blonde bombshell". It also used to turn their skin yellow too!

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @peasimo. Your post would be improved if it included an accessible reference :-)

Answer (score 0):

Bombshell may have come from the humor and racy comments in Captain Billy's Whiz Bang magazine which began publishing in 1919.  From what I understand many attractive women were described using words from the Great War, as the title of the magazine itself.

Answer (score 0):

Bombshell. Having 9-years in the military, I need to bring this perspective. A bombshell is just a casing. It looks dangerous, but its interior is vapid.

Blondes are culturally defined as vapid, but they look hot -- like a live round.

We've demonstrated that bombshell was used long before it was used as the title of Jean Harlow's movie.

As for the actual origin...its origin can be found in the same place any great new word can found -- in the corner of the mouth of a grunt standing ankle high in the muck. When the new word finally meets the air, a few dark chuckles emerge within the unit, then some doof takes it to his next unit and acts like it's his word, and so on and so forth.